# Change CSP default directory to use an existing PAYASYOUGO suscripcion directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a client who has an azure payasyougo account, it has inside office 365 services and Azure resources. These services uses a common Azure directory.

The client has decided to use our services as CSP service provider and the solution requires the following:

1. The new destination CSP suscriptions must handle the same active directory of the original payasyougo suscription.
2. The Azure resources must be migrated from the source subscription to the target subscription keeping all the permissions intact.
3. The source subscription has 4 custom domains with their respective users being synchronized through Azure AD connect. All of the must be configured in the target subscription.

Is it possible to link the directory of the existing subscription paysasyougo with the new target subscription CSP?

Note: The directory change option is available in the source subscription payasyou, but it is not available under the CSP subscription which is where it is needed.

Further details: Both PAYSASYOUGO and CSP azure subcriptions resides on different tenants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would 100% recommend reaching out to Microsoft for the specifics on this especially since you are a CSP and already have an established relationship with them!

Microsoft do provide some documentation on the questions you are asking though:

1. At the very least you would be able to migrate it or copy it across / grant permissions to the new subscriptions to manage the old AD that's providing access, However moving the Azure AD I believe would haven as per the same answer to Question 2
2. How to Migrate subscriptions from PAYG to Azure CSP:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/migration/migration-from-payg-to-csp

   - Further Reading;
     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/switch-azure-subscriptions-to-a-different-partner
3. This maybe possible but would most likely cause an outage.

Detailed Blog on the process:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/08/26/azure-subscription-migration-to-csp/

What resources are available in Azure CSP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/overview/azure-csp-available-services

***Again 100% I would recommend getting an official answer from Microsoft***

Comment: Thank you Lachie for the pieces of advice. I've already done this assessment along with the MS appointed engineer and it seems he does not have a final approach for this scenario. However, I think it can be accomplished with new instances of Azure connect and pointing them to the new subscription.
As for migration from pay as you go to csp, it seems not possible since that subscription has office 365 products attached on it and therefore, can not be converted directly into CSP as per is documented by MS. I'll try to escalate this request to a deeper MS support. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @BrianOtero sounds like you have the best answer then! When office365 gets involved things get complicated real quick.

Comment: By last, after trying with Azure AD connect sync process, it gave failures since it does not support synchronization from a single on-premises ad towards two different subscriptions.
The only solution for this scenario is to make sure both CSP and PayAsYouGo subscriptions reside in the SAME TENANT and not in isolated tenants as is seen in the current environment. That solution worked and both subscriptions are now sharing the same Azure AD and also the custom domains on it. Azure AD Connect
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-topologies